# Flickering in ios animation with CGAffineTransformMakeRotate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewanimation, cgaffinetransform

I am implementing Animation with CGAffineTransform.
What i have done is took a UIView with size height and width say 100. then put UIImageView with y position as 50 in above mentioned UIView. so its at center of view.
Now i have another same type of UIview and UIImage combination in above UIView.
So Heirarchy is like
1)UIView
2)UIImageView
2)UIView
3)UIImageView.

This is to achieve 2 level pendulum animation ..
**But While animation going on it shows flickering of main UIView and Also second call of doanimation method is also not working properly**
Below is my Code..

```
-(void)startAnimation:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender;
{

    [self stopAnimation];
    isAnimating = YES;
    switch (sender.view.tag) {
        case 501:
            animatingFullView=fullRightHand;
            animatingSmallView=smallRightHand;
            break;
        case 502:
            animatingFullView=fullRightHand;
            animatingSmallView=smallRightHand;
            break;
        case 503:
            animatingFullView=fullLeftHand;
            animatingSmallView=smallLeftHand;
            break;
        case 504:
            animatingFullView=fullLeftHand;
            animatingSmallView=smallLeftHand;
            break;
        case 505:
            animatingFullView=fullRightLeg;
            animatingSmallView=smallRightLeg;
            break;
        case 506:
            animatingFullView=fullRightLeg;
            animatingSmallView=smallRightLeg;
            break;
        case 507:
            animatingFullView=fullLeftLeg;
            animatingSmallView=smallLeftLeg;
            break;
        case 508:
            animatingFullView=fullLeftLeg;
            animatingSmallView=smallLeftLeg;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


    [self doAnimation:M_PI/2 withFullView:animatingFullView smallView:animatingSmallView];
}

-(void) doAnimation:(float )rotationAngle withFullView:(UIView *)fullView smallView:(UIView *)smallView{
    rotationAngleOriginal=rotationAngle;
    if(!isAnimating)
        return;

    fullView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1*rotationAngle);
    smallView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1*rotationAngle);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse  | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        CGAffineTransform transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngle);
        fullView.transform =transform;
        smallView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rotationAngle);

    }completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         [self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];
         if(rotationAngle>0.0 && (isAnimating==YES)){
             [self doAnimation:(rotationAngle/1.2) withFullView:fullView smallView:smallView];
         }
     }];
}![enter image description here][1]
```